Ceiling fan placement for open concept
Question: Where should I place a ceiling fan in my 'open concept' floorplan? Option 1, Option 2, or somewhere else? Details below.
We live in a duplex with an open concept first floor. We are installing a ceiling fan and need to decide where to place it. The primary purpose is cooling. There are two contenders (see image below):

Directly above the couch/living area.
Above some dead space, roughly in the center of the floor, hoping to produce cooling airflow that reaches the entire first floor.

Some notes about the space and the fan:

Approximately 45 feet deep and 20 feet wide
9 foot ceilings
A fireplace provides some separation between the living/dining areas. It extends out about 5 feet from the wall, and is about 5 feet tall
With a small downrod, the fan will be about 8.5 feet above the floor
60 inch fan-blade span, 3-bladed fan, rated for 2.4k to 7.3k CFM (low setting, high setting).
The only openable windows are on the back wall (top of image below, which is a sliding patio door in the kitchen/dining area), and in the (enclosed) den.



Where should I place a ceiling fan in my 'open concept' floorplan? Option 1, Option 2, or somewhere else?
Edited into the original post as well.

A 60" fan is typically recommended for a room no larger than 20'x20'. You have more than double that area, you may want to consider a second fan.

Subjective questions like this are off topic. We have no way of assessing performance and perception objectively through the internet. Please see the [help].

If you would like the entire space to feel cooler, your space will require at least 2 fans.   See the Ceiling fan guide.
If you are only concerned with cooling yourself when watching TV, the couch option would work best. However others in the kitchen or at the table may be uncomfortable.
Two fans may be the best solution. One over the couch, one between the island and table.  Either can be turned off if needed, but having both on would help circulate the air in the entire area.

A fan circulates air; it doesn't cool it. If the airflow is blowing directly on you, you may feel cooler due to evaporation. So where you want the fan depends on where the humans are going to spend most of their time.
The fan may also even out the temperature in the room, so it will mix colder air at floor level with warmer air higher up; depending on how much temperature differential there is and how stratified the room is without the fan, this may affect perceived temperatures But that tends to be more effective in not wasting hot air near the ceiling then in bringing cold air up from the floor.
A fan may also encourage mixing of air between rooms, though a ceiling fan is less effective at this then a horizontally directed fan blowing air from one room to another. Again, whether that makes things seem warmer or colder depends on the relative temperature of the two rooms.
So you may be reaching for the wrong device to solve your problem.

Understood that a fan could mix air of different temperatures, but doesn't magically, intrinsically change the temperature of the air it moves around :).
We've not e.g. measured at 8' vs 1' level, but we perceive no temperature hot/cold spots. So it's about the perception of cooler/fresher air, not changing the temperature anywhere.
We'll be sitting at the dining table or the couch for extended periods. But we'll be all around the space, and there will often be people throughout the space simultaneously. This has me leaning towards option 2 (the central placement).
